# APIGee cannot retrieve application keys for account

Tags: apigee

I use APIGee for both API Proxy and Documentation, using a customized documentation site.

Following the recent APIGee outage this weekend, when I access my registered application list using my personal login on the documentation portal, I can no longer retrieve my application keys.

I get the error

> STATUS: 404 - Not Found; Communication with the Apigee endpoint is
>   compromised. Cannot get API Products List.

The strange thing is that if I use my admin login at accounts.apigee.com, I can see 2 of my 3 applications listed... but one has disappeared. And more worryingly, this portal provides different application keys to the ones that were initially provided though the documentation portal.

I haven't been able to find any good documentation on this. How are these two sites linked together? Why are the keys different on both sites? What has caused my data to go missing?!

Comment: Can you be more specific with what API call is being made when you get the 404?  Is it something like https://api.enterprise.apgiee.com/v1/o/{your org}/etc... or are you hitting the Apigee BaaS at https://api.usergrid.com/{your org}/etc...?

Answer (score 0):

Tadhg -

This sounds like an issue that needs investigation by Apigee Global Support.

Would you please create an Apigee Support case?  Please provide any applicable details, including your Organization name, the API call(s) you are making, the 3 applications you expect to see, and any other details you think might be helpful to diagnose.

Thanks!

Comment: I've had an open case with API Gee support on this since Monday, eventually I gave up waiting posted it here! The ticket number is 817047.
Thanks! Tadhg